# Converting arrray values to integer from request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array-difference

I want to `array_diff()` two arrays in Laravel. The first array looks like this:

```
    array:4 [
  0 => 7248
  1 => 7249
  2 => 7250
  3 => 7251
]
```

the second one:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "7248"
  1 => "7249"
  2 => "7250"
  3 => "7251"
]
```

this one I get with `$request->request->get('ids', []);`.

**How can I convert one array to either strings or integers?
As these arrays can grow large, I don't really want to convert every single value one at a time.**

**Update:**

array_diff() is doing it's job, altough there are strings vs. integers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to convert anything. `array_diff()` uses `(string) $item1 === (string) $item2`, so it works right out of the box.

Comment: PHP is intelligent enough while doing comparisons:-https://3v4l.org/apMnU   Or https://3v4l.org/am8Mp

Comment: thank you for the explanation. if php is "intelligent enough" is another topic :) as i am doing after that  a merge i have some values as string, some as int in there... which I don't like...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$newArray = array_map('intval', $request->request->get('ids', []));
```

This code will convert your string fields to int so you can compare.

Comment: Hmmm why is the downvote for this answer? It will work for OP's question.

Comment: Actually, that's correct answer, because it answers on OP's question precisely that is "_How can I convert one array to either strings or integers?_". Saying that `array_diff` won't work was just a distraction :)

Comment: Thank you. Although its not really necessary, but it makes the resulting array better. :)